# Create a Sublime Text 3 .sublime-completions autocomplete file on mac

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

The Sublime Text [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html) is clear on the syntax for HTML, but not clear on where to place the file for mac using version 3. I want to generate my own auto-completes for Plain Text. Ideally allowing me to down/up arrow through a list of likely auto-completes.

```
{
   "scope": "text.html - source - meta.tag, punctuation.definition.tag.begin",

   "completions":
   [
      { "trigger": "a", "contents": "<a href=\"$1\">$0</a>" },
      { "trigger": "abbr\t<abbr>", "contents": "<abbr>$0</abbr>" },
      { "trigger": "acronym", "contents": "<acronym>$0</acronym>" }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All package resource files need to be stored in a Package for Sublime to be able to find and load it. For your own customizations, the appropriate place to place the file is in your `User` package, which you can find via `Preferences > Browse Packages` from the menu.On MacOS, that would be `Sublime Text > Preferences > Browse Packages`.

In order to have completions for plain text, you need to change the `scope` from the HTML specific scope to one for plain text.

In order to determine the scope that you want to apply (which also counts for things like Key Bindings, Snippets, Build Systems, and so on) you can select `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name` from the menu (see the menu for the key binding assigned to this) to see what the full scope is for the current cursor location.

As evidenced from the `scope` you mentioned in your question, scopes can be quite complex to allow you to dial in as much specificity as you want.

For the case of simple plain text, as evidenced by the command I mentioned above, the following is the example completions set to work in plain text:

```json
{
   "scope": "text.plain",

   "completions":
   [
      { "trigger": "a", "contents": "<a href=\"$1\">$0</a>" },
      { "trigger": "abbr\t<abbr>", "contents": "<abbr>$0</abbr>" },
      { "trigger": "acronym", "contents": "<acronym>$0</acronym>" }
   ]
}
```

Note that along with the location of the file, the extension is also important, otherwise Sublime won't know what it's supposed to contain.

Comment: I added the above text as a file named 'plain.sublime-completions' to /Users/UserName/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User. When I'm in a new plain text file, I can now enter 'abbr' and press ctrl-spacebar and confirm it works. Thank you very much!